# NoJMSMessageIdException: MISSING_JMS_MESSAGE_ID

Tags: python, stomp, activemq-artemis

I'm using Python to send a STOMP message to a queue on ActiveMQ Artemis. However, when my Spring JMS application receives the message I get:

```
NoJMSMessageIdException: MISSING_JMS_MESSAGE_ID.
```

I tried to set like a header or property different values like `JMSMessageID`, `msgID`, `MESSAGE_ID`, etc.

I found out that my application validates the message using [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSMessageID--). I tried to send it with [prefix `id`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13943/WebLogic.Messaging.IMessage.JMSMessageID.html), but it didn't help. What does it expect? How to send it by stomp in Python?

The [documentation of Python STOMP client](https://stomppy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#sending-and-receiving-messages) has such example but it doesn't explain how to send this JMS id:

> Protocol12.send(destination, body, content_type=None, headers=None,
> **keyword_headers)
> Send a message to a destination in the messaging system (as per
> https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#SEND)
> Parameters:
>
> - **destination** (*str*) – the destination (such as a message
>   queue - for example ‘/queue/test’ - or a message topic)
> - **body**: the content of the message
> - **content_type** (*str*): the MIME type of message
> - **headers** (*dict*): additional headers to send in the message frame
> - **keyword_headers**: any additional headers the broker requires

My code:

```py
import stomp
import json


jsonRequest = {
    "data": {
        "key": "value"

}}


class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, frame):
        print('received an error "%s"' % frame.body)

    def on_message(self, frame):
        print('received a message "%s"' % frame.body)


conn = stomp.Connection([('host', 63001)])
conn.set_listener('', MyListener())
conn.connect('user', 'password', wait=True)
conn.subscribe(destination='queue', id=1, ack='auto')
conn.send(destination='queue', body=json.dumps(jsonRequest),  MESSAGE_ID='e5bf8c3d-0dc4-11ed-a28a-544d36153f8c', JMSMessageID='ID:e5bf8c3d-0dc4-11ed-a28a-544d36153f5c', headers={'MESSAGE_ID': 'ID:e5bf8c3d-0dc4-11ed-a28a-544d36153f5c', 'JMSCorrelationID': '123278256677', 'JMSReplyTo': 'queue'},
MSGUID="3e4fb627-85df-4b37-b37b-1070c7893c99", TotalNumberMsg=1, CurrentNumberMsg=1, UIPSYSTEMDATA=72)

test = MyListener()
```

And I have error in log of back-end service:

```
2022-07-27 20:10:53 [,] [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2] ERROR service.jms.listener.base.AbstractArtemisMessageListener - Exception while processing message MISSING_JMS_MESSAGE_ID
service.exception.NoJMSMessageIdException: MISSING_JMS_MESSAGE_ID
```

When I send message by JMS ToolBox it has this id:

```
2022-07-27 18:58:03 [,] [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2] INFO  service.jms.listener.base.AbstractArtemisMessageListener - Message from srv: ActiveMQMessage[ID:e5bf8c3d-0dc4-11ed-a28a-544d36153f0c]:PERSISTENT/ClientLargeMessageImpl[messageID=318412845, durable=true, address=queue,userID=e5bf8c3d-0dc4-11ed-a28a-544d36153f0c,properties=TypedProperties[__AMQ_CID=JMSToolBox-1657948224556,TotalNumberMsg=1,JMSReplyTo=queue://,_AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE=1,MSGUID=3e4fb627-85df-4b37-b37b-1070c7893c82,SERVICENAME=service,JMSCorrelationID=5515D5431364567,_AMQ_VALIDATED_USER=ACTIVEMQ.CLUSTER.ADMIN.USER,CurrentNumberMsg=1,UIPSYSTEMDATA=063224508,_AMQ_LARGE_SIZE=308737]] with correlationId: 5515D5431364567
```

Through the STOMP it has NULL value:

```
2022-07-27 19:12:52 [,] [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2] INFO  service.jms.listener.base.AbstractArtemisMessageListener - Message from srv: ActiveMQMessage[null]:NON-PERSISTENT/ClientLargeMessageImpl[messageID=318581407, durable=false, address=queue,userID=null,properties=TypedProperties[content-length=110919,destination=queue,JMSReplyTo=queue,TotalNumberMsg=1,_AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE=1,MSGUID=3e4fb627-85df-4b37-b37b-1070c7893c99,SERVICENAME=service,JMSCorrelationID=123278256677,_AMQ_VALIDATED_USER=ACTIVEMQ.CLUSTER.ADMIN.USER,CurrentNumberMsg=1,UIPSYSTEMDATA=72,_AMQ_LARGE_SIZE=110919,messageID=125774553292,JMSType=NULL-value]] with correlationId: 123278256677
```

Comment: @JustinBertram thanks for answer, I've added this information in the initial message.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: Any feedback here?

Answer (score 1):

Section 3.4.3 of the JMS 2 specification states (emphasis mine):

> The JMSMessageID header field contains a value that uniquely identifies
> each message **sent by a provider**.
>
> When a message is sent, JMSMessageID is ignored. When the send method
> returns it contains a **provider-assigned** value.

The same basic text is in section 3.4.3 of the JMS 1.1 specification as well.

The point the specification is making here is that the `JMSMessageID` is assigned to the message when an application sends a message using the JMS client library supplied by "the provider" (ActiveMQ Artemis in this case). However, you are **not** sending your message with a JMS client library. You're sending a message with a STOMP client library. Therefore, the message has no `JMSMessageID` assigned to it.

Furthermore, setting the `JMSMessageID` is actually *optional* even for JMS clients. See [`javax.jms.MessageProducer#setDisableMessageID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html#setDisableMessageID-boolean-).

Therefore, your `service.jms.listener.base.AbstractArtemisMessageListener` class should not consider it an error if [`javax.jms.Message#getJMSMessageID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSMessageID--) returns `null` as this is a perfectly valid possibility.